# Using keys/passwords instead of site login

Tags: security, authentication

I'm thinking if it's a good idea to have a Web app which doesn't require a site login. This is for something like a public wiki where you just want to jump in and create stuff but still have a way to control access.

Content can be read/edited by the content creator (or a few other people).

What would be good references or existing apps that implement something like this?

EDIT: The closest similar "no signup" site I could find was [ImageShack](http://imageshack.us) though there you can't edit what you've already submitted.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't quite know how to implement this. Maybe with user scripts, like Greasemonkey? Another option would be to use an already-existing login, like Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc.

Comment: No it shouldn't require a login, though the content can be associated with a login.

Comment: Re: ImageShack - This site has literally no authentication. Anybody can post anything, and you have very little idea (besides, possibly, IP address) who posted what. Is that what you want? I was under the impression that you wanted to distribute a "public key" which would automatically allow access to those who had the key (no need to manually enter it).

Comment: @Ryan Yes that describes what I want, public keys or passwords for accessing the resources. The similarity with ImageShack is that I also would like accounts but you're not required to have one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure on the value of this type of a system. Once the password/key has been in circulation for `x time`, they will be rendered useless.

I recommend rather going for something that's more scalable and open, with a good example being [OpenID](http://openid.net/). [Here's](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries) a good library of implementations for it as well.

Comment: The other idea is that you'd be able to associate the secured content with an account eventually.

Comment: @Jerome - I would rather go with an account based role system, rather than simply trying to assign a role alone (which seems what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: The idea is to reduce the barrier to entry -- no signup required. As I said, I intend to have the user associate the content with an account if he/she wishes.

Comment: @Jerome - Well then in the context of your example, make it an open system that need x votes from the community to commit information. To be able to vote on the posts you can then signup, or alternatively wait until the community approves the content.

Comment: The requirement is to have some access control -- content can be read/edited by the content creator (or a few other people). I've updated the description, might not have been that clear.